# MySQL Wordpress extract data from meta_value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can pairs of meta_key, meta_value be processed in a table in which each meta_key is a column?

Background: I need to get for each purchase made in Learnpress (Wordpress Plugin) the payment method, the quantity, and the user which made the payment among others between two dates.

Learnpress saves the purchases as posts, and the attributes of each purchase as pairs of meta_key, meta_value in wp_postmeta. If wp_postmeta had different attributes in different columns, I could do something like this:

```
SELECT attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 FROM wp_postmeta, wp_posts 
WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID;
```

However, each post has N rows in wp_postmeta, one row for each attribute. How can the data be joined so I can get a table in which a row has all the attributes of each post?

Example:

wp_post table

```
ID   (Other Columns)
1
2
3

wp_postmeta table:
ID    post_id    meta_key        meta_value 
1     1          user            testuser1
2     1          payment_method  paypal
3     1          quantity        25
(Other rows, with the same post_id, one for each attribute of this purchase)
4     2          user            testuser2
5     2          payment_method  credit_card
6     2          quantity        50

Desired Result:
Post_ID    user        payment_method        quantity        (Other attributes)
1          testuser1   paypal                25
2          testuser2   credit_card           50
```

Note: Some posts have more postmeta rows associated with them than others. If a post does not have an attribute in postmeta it should be null in the final table.

How can something like this be accomplish?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_postmeta;

CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,post_id INT NOT NULL
,meta_key VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,meta_value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(post_id,meta_key)
);

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES
(1,1,'user','testuser1'),
(2,1,'payment_method','paypal'),
(3,1,'quantity',25),
(4,2,'user','testuser2'),
(5,2,'payment_method','credit_card'),
(6,2,'quantity','50');

SELECT x.post_id 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.meta_key = 'user'            THEN x.meta_value END) user     
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.meta_key = 'payment_method'  THEN x.meta_value END) payment     
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.meta_key = 'quantity'        THEN x.meta_value END) quantity
  FROM wp_postmeta x
 GROUP
    BY post_id;

+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| post_id | user      | payment     | quantity |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | testuser1 | paypal      | 25       |
|       2 | testuser2 | credit_card | 50       |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Performance might benefit if you can figure out a way to separate values out into discrete tables according to data type.

Comment: Works like a charm. I adapted this query to create a temporary table with the needed meta_key attributes, and then join it with the other tables. Thanks!

Comment: @Raul. Good. The temporary table is fine, but unnecessary; A subquery would work just as well.